# How can I use Zoom in JQplot live data chart?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using JQplot to show live data in chart, it works fine for me But when I am trying to zoom, browser is getting hang. Is there any way I can zoom to see details.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you currently zooming that is causing the browser to hang?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fracu/HrZcj/

Comment: It's not my code but I am using same with data coming from websocket, I am using atmosphere plugin for websocket.

Comment: I am using x-axis daterendrer which is causing problem,          axes: {xaxis: {renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
tickOptions: {formatString: '%H:%M:%S'},numberTicks: 7}},